# How can I align text to some curve?

Tags: gimp, text, alignment, text-wrap, text-on-path

How can I align text in GIMP so one of its sides “touches” some path or the text is placed *inside* path?

Example:

The text is aligned so right side of text line bounding box is at the number 4.

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. GIMP has very limited text formatting capabilities. It's just not the right kind of application for this. You can move it manually though - just type each line of text on its own layer and move them into position.  You may be able to do this automatically using more suitable software, such as with desktop publishing software like Scribus where you can use text wrapping.

Comment: Note that the [bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) is normally a rectangle.What you are mentioning is the outline (I think).